# Reversing an sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I got this algorithm that sort int[] a from low to high.

```
public static void sortering(int[] a){
    int temp;               

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
        if(a[i] > a[j]){
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

What i want to do is to reverse it, make it sort from high to low. I thought this would be a walk in the park doing something like this:

```
public static void sorteringU(int[] a){
    int temp;

    for(int i = a.length; i < a.length; i--){
        for(int j = i - 1; j < a.length; j--){
            if(a[i] > a[j]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wrong, this apparently does nothing. 
Anyone willing to help?

Edit: Thx Jesper and Satya, it worked.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is change in the original code is `if(a[i] > a[j])` to `if(a[i] < a[j])`.

Comment: change this if(a[i] > a[j]){  to if(a[i] < a[j]){  and se if it is working

Comment: `if(a[i] > a[j])` this is where logic is hidden not in loop taversing

Answer (score 3):

This is enough:

```
public static void sorteringU(int[] a){
    int temp;               

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
        if(a[i] < a[j]){ // Change ">" to "<"
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void sortering(int[] a){
    int temp;               

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
    if(a[i] < a[j]){
        temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
    }
}
}
```

try this, instead of `if(a[i] > a[j])`, make it  `if(a[i] < a[j])`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
                 note -1   note condition change
                    V       V
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
  for(int j = i - 1;    j >= 0; j--){
```

It needs to be `-1`, as arrays go from `0` to `length-1`, you previously started off at 0, thus you need to start off at the other side, i.e. `length-1`.

You need to check `>= 0`. If you check `< length`, it will go on forever, since it only gets smaller, so it will never be larger than `length`. If you compare against 0, it will stop as soon as it gets to the beginning of the array.

But **just changing `if(a[i] > a[j])` to `if(a[i] < a[j])` would be a simpler fix**.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me you do not need to change the travering loop :). Sorting logic is hidden into `if(a[i] > a[j])`. Simply change change `if(a[i] > a[j])` to `if(a[i] < a[j])`. It will work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
        if(a[i] < a[j]){
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bubble sort algorithm , just change the comparator method will be ok

```
    change it from if(a[i] > a[j]) to if(a[i] < a[j])
```

let other code untouched.

Comment: IMO it is not bubble sort.

Comment: It's still not bubble sort. Bubble sort only swaps adjacent elements. It's more like some variant of [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).